# $P(|X|<r)$ for $X$ a standard normal in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, reference-request

If $X$ is a standard normal random variable in $\mathbb{R}^n$, is there a known formula for $P(|X| < r)$ for $r>0$? Here $|X|$ means the usual Euclidean distance.

Comment: @Yikai, yes Euclidean distance.

Comment: And are the entries in $X$ independent?

Comment: Assuming that $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, I_n)$, the probability $\Bbb{P}(|X| < r)$ is not hard to simplify using the spherical coordinates change. The result is well-summarized by the name of [*chi distribution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution).

Comment: If $n=2$, the result is simpler than expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
X_1^2 + X_2^2 + \cdots + X_n^2 \sim \chi^2(n)
$$
thus
$$
\|X\| = \sqrt{X_1^2 + X_2^2 + \cdots + X_n^2} \sim \chi(n)
$$
assuming independent $X_1$, $X_2$, $\cdots$, $X_n$.